# How do I check if a particular object exist or not in a JavaScript array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, find

How do I check if a particular object exist or not in a JavaScript array of objects?

```
// Main array of objects
var dailogMappingData = [
    {
        "name": "AgglomerativeCluster",
        "size": 3938
    }, {
        "name": "CommunityStructure",
        "size": 3812
    }, {
        "name": "HierarchicalCluster",
        "size": 6714
    }
];


// search object to find in the above array is exist or not: 
var findObj = {
    "name": "CommunityStructure",
    "size": 3812
};


var m, n;

for (m = 0; m < this.dailogMappingData.length; m++) {
    for (n = 0; n < mapKeys.length; n++) {
        if (this.dailogMappingData[m][mapKeys[n]] === newObj[mapKeys[n]]) {
            isInArray = true;
        } else {
            isInArray = false;
        }

    }
    if (isInArray) {
        break;
    }
}
```

How to find an object in an array, or find out if it exists or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

Comment: /initialize the flag
var flag =true;
for(var i=0;i>dailogMappingData.length;i++){
 //Getting one by one object from array
 var obj1 = dailogMappingData[i];

 if(Object.keys(obj1).length==Object.keys(obj2).length){
      for(key in obj1) { 
         if(obj1[key] == obj2[key]) {
            continue;
         }else {
           flag=false;
           break;
        }
      }
    }else{
    flag=false;
}
}

Comment: Need to compare all properties in the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `name` property is unique you can simply check if there are any objects in array with the same name:

```js
var dailogMappingData = [{
  "name": "AgglomerativeCluster",
  "size": 3938
}, {
  "name": "CommunityStructure",
  "size": 3812
}, {
  "name": "HierarchicalCluster",
  "size": 6714
}];

var findObj = {
  "name": "CommunityStructure",
  "size": 3812
};

const isInArray = dailogMappingData.some(item => item.name === findObj.name);

console.log(isInArray);
```

If you can't rely on `name` property and need to compare all properties, you may want to use `isEqual` function from [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.14#isEqual)

```js
var dailogMappingData = [{
  "name": "AgglomerativeCluster",
  "size": 3938
}, {
  "name": "CommunityStructure",
  "size": 3812
}, {
  "name": "HierarchicalCluster",
  "size": 6714
}];

var findObj = {
  "name": "CommunityStructure",
  "size": 3812
};

const isInArray = dailogMappingData.some(item => _.isEqual(findObj, item));

console.log(isInArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: expecting the second option but without Lodash can we do it with javascript

Comment: In this case I would suggest checking answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)